# Select a value from input combo box using Selenium using xpath for a reachjs control

Tags: reactjs, selenium, xpath, automation

Hi Need to select "New South Wales" using `By.xpath()` any suggestions please?

This is a reactjs page [jedwatson.github.io/react-select](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select)

```
<div class="Select-control">
    <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value">
        <div class="Select-value State-NSW">
            <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-item">New South Wales</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" value="" style="width: 5px; box-sizing: content-box;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal;"></div>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value" aria-label="Clear value">
        <span class="Select-clear">×</span>
    </span>
    <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
        <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Tried with the below code without success

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@role='combobox'][@value='New York"']")).click();;
```

Below exception was observed

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@role='combobox'][@value='New York']"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.86)
```

Comment: are u facing any exception ?

Comment: @Tuks updated the question by adding exception

Comment: Try with this and let me know your outcome-
```driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'New South Wales')]"));```

Comment: @Saad i get the below error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'New York')]"}

Comment: @Savio I can't see the New York in html. are you sure there is New York in your html.?
You asked about selecting New South Wales in your question not New York.

Comment: @Saad this is a [reactjs] page https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ here is the link

Comment: @Savio There is no New york in the drop down list.

Comment: Ok my mistake. You are trying to select the city. Pardon

Comment: @Saad the values are dynamically generated using reactjs

Comment: New South Wales's XPath is //*[@id="react-select-2--value-item"]
Could you try this ?

Comment: If your question is yet to be resolved let me know the exact manual steps you are trying to automate.

Comment: If your question is yet to be resolved let me know the exact manual steps you are trying to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the below step to select your desired element

1. Click on the down arrow of dropdown
2. Select the desired option

Here is the code for same :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'States')]/..//span[@class='Select-arrow']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-2--option-1")).click();
```

**Updated**

Use the below method to select the value dynamically based on text :

```
public void selectCombo(String valueText)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'States')]/..//span[@class='Select-arrow']")).click();
    WebElement dropdownValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+valueText+"')]"));
    dropdownValue.click();
}
```

Call this method from your code and pass the value which you want to select

e.g.

```
new TestClass().selectCombo("Tasmania");
```

Comment: thanks for the above code, able to click and select, but how do i do it based on dynamic text?

Comment: Is there any way to click by Index ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the xpath `//*[@role="option" and text()='New South Wales']`

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@role='option'][@text='New York']"} got the above error

Comment: please use text() method instead of @text, for example //span[@role='option'][text()='‌​New York']

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@role='option'][text()='New York']"}